# ElasticSearch Indexing Multiple Types

Tags: wcf, elasticsearch

Can I Index multiple types, from a JSON file carrying  XML's inside?

https://www.elastic.co/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets

Comment: And what does your question have to do with the link you posted?

Comment: Wrong link sorry, anyway i have come across so many post's about indexing using elasticsearch but no one, is indexing a type with different versions to it. what i am trying to do is to save an instance of the same file with different versions, and then i can revert back to the older files if i need to.

Comment: http://joelabrahamsson.com/extending-aspnet-mvc-music-store-with-elasticsearch/ something like this.